# How can the Higgs field "sense" that the temperature is high enough to restore the broken symmetry above this temperature?

Tags: phase-transition, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In the picture below of the potential of the Higgs field, we can see that
the field has its highest energy if the field is zero, i.e. if no Higgs particles are present.

The symmetry is restored at an extremely high temperature, leaving us with a Higgs field that is zero everywhere, i.e. no Higgs particles are present at that high energy.

I can't imagine how the Higgs field "knows" that the temperature is so high that the Higgs field evaporates. Of course, heat is transferred to the Higgs field but how can the field "sense" this high temperature. Are the energies involved in the collisions of particle fields with the Higgs field high enough to let the broken symmetry evolve into the non-broken symmetry?

For almost **all** phase transitions (like the one to a superconducting state, to a Bose-Einstein condensate, the ones involving solid-liquid-gas or the ones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition), except the ones involving SSB) I can see how they relate to temperature. But not for this one.

So, what's going on in the transition from the presence of the Higgs field to the non-presence (evaporation)when the temperature is high enough? And what stuff is the "carrier" of this temperature? The Higgs field itself?

[image: Higgs potential]

Comment: Hi. I don't hold a definite answer to your question but may I ask this: why specifically the Higgs field? How would you describe other phase transition in other contexts- how do the fields there "know" what's happening and the transition happens? Just a question, to understand what difference you see. I ' m not specifying a certain phase transition example, for you to choose whatever you want. Thanks.

Comment: At a high enough temperature, there *will* be Higgs particles everywhere, because the average collision in the general plasma of particles will be energetic enough to produce them... In some sense, the answer to the question is, that the Higgs field interacts with the other fields. However I admit I can't answer the question to my own satisfaction, because I don't understand how to interpolate between thermal field theory (formalism for finite temperature QFT) and ordinary QFT (formalism for zero temperature). The vev is zero in thermal field theory, and nonzero in ordinary QFT...

Comment: ... but there must be some interpolating formalism. First four references in section 2.2 of http://dark.ft.uam.es/mununiverse/images/tesis_andrew.pdf are classic works where this was first studied.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack-Do you think that in all phase transitions a symmetry is spontaneously broken (or restored)?

Comment: @descheleschilder Really? I am assuming you can understand I am referring to such situations even if in general not all transitions come from SSB.

Comment: And I specifically wrote I let you decide whatever example you may want. I wrote: "I ' m not specifying a certain phase transition example, for you to choose whatever you want". Thanks.

Comment: Well, let's take the simplest(?) example: the phase transition from ice to liquid water. What are the fields here? The water-molecule fields?

Comment: I am not asking you that. And ice to water is not a simple example, is one we are used to. Take Bose-Einstein condensation, take a feromagnet, take hard disks in 2D. And if you want, yes, take water. The fields are the molecules as you call them; what are the fields in the Ising model? The spins of the atoms. You can do field theory without doing high-energy particle theory.

Comment: But what I was aksing you is why concentrate at the Higgs field when there are still other examples of SSB phase transitions that are, too, temperature dependent. How do the bosons in a boson condensate "know" the temperature?

Comment: What I am asking you has to do with how you understand what you ask, because from the phrasing, it doesn't- for me- make much sense. Take low energy QCD and you have effective models that describe through the SSB of chiral symmetry the production of pions. Go to the high energy limit and you do perturbative QCD; a phase transition has occurred. I was interested in seeing how you understand the problem, why you are phrasing it the way you do, if you have study it. -1 from 'cause you didn't try to answer a simple question aimed to help you, and me decide whether I should write you an answer.

Comment: Either you don't understand what I am saying or you are trying to dodge a question with another - irrelevant- one. As I said, you had all the examples you wanted, to explain to me how and why you understand your post as you did- but you are asking me if you can do field theory. Thank you.

Comment: So my question could better be: "Hoe do fields know what the temperature is when the symmetry(what kind of symmetry is that, by the way?)  breaks or is restored?". Maybe I chose this example because I was just thinking about it, not realizing that low energy (very low in the case of an Einstein condensate, of which I didn't know that symmetry is involved) also show this kind of behavior and temperature is very prominent present in my example (and even more in the hypothetical case of the symmetry breaking in the case of the breaking of the symmetry between the three basic forces).

Comment: Almost all phase transitions (to superconduction, to a Bose-Einstein condensate, the ones involving solid-liquid-gas, to superfluidity, you name it!) are easy to understand in connection with temperature. They don't  have a connection with SSB, which the phase transition of the Higgs field **does** have. In this case, **can't** see how temperature induces this phase transition. That's why I choose this example. Thanks!